# Getting a number that represents the level of an object/nested object inside an object

Tags: javascript

Consider the following Javascript object

```
var items = [{
    content: 'A_lvl0',
}, {
    content: 'B_lvl0',
}, {
    content: 'C_lvl0',
    children: [{
        content: 'C_1_lvl1',
    }, {
        content: 'C_2_lvl1',
        children: [{
            content: 'C_1_lvl2'
        }, {
            content: 'C_2_lvl2',
            children:[{
                content: 'C_1_lvl3'
            }, {
                content: 'C_2_lvl3'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        content: 'C_3_lvl1'
    }]
}];
```

the lvlx you see in the content property of the object where x represents how deeply the object is nested, suppose i had a reference to an object inside the above object and wanted to return the value of x which is how deeply the object is nested, i know i have to use recursion but i am not sure how to keep track of the top lvl

i was able to print the nested content of all objects using the following function

```
var scanObj = function (obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        console.log(obj[i].content);
        if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
            scanObj(obj[i].children);
        }
    }
};
```

but now what i am trying to write is

```
var getlvlByRef = function (obj,subobject) {
       //return lvl
    };




var getlvlByPropertyValue = function (obj,propertyname,propertyvalue) {
       //return lvl
    };
```

and my problem is i am not sure how to keep track when i reach the last nested lvl, could you please point me to the right way?

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eG3qR/

Comment: You reach the last nested level when the object you are inspecting has no `children` property. Is that right?

Comment: @CharlieKilian yes exactly

Comment: in your current scanObj implementation you kind of already do taht with the if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) -- if the obj doesn't have that property, it will evaluate to false and not run again.

Comment: @Brodie my main problem is finding the lvl with recursion, i know when to stop but i cant seem to find a way to keep track, how would i make the scanObj function print the lvl of the current object too?

Comment: For `getlvlByRef`, what is passed in for `obj` and `subobj`? And the same question for `getlvlByPropertyValue`; what do you supply to the parameters and what should they return?

Comment: subobject is a reference to the internal object, angular does get it for me when using ng-repeat inside a nested directive, for getlvlByPropertyValue(items,'content','C_1_lvl3') should return the lvl as a number which is 3

Comment: Well I'm late to the party, but here's the fiddle to my solution anyway. http://jsfiddle.net/7SAJB/7/

Comment: @CharlieKilian pretty lovely thanks a million, enjoy your party!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I created a fiddle for my solution

http://jsfiddle.net/3W5qY/3/

```
function getlvlByPropertyValue(obj, propertyName, propertyValue, level){    
    if(level == undefined) level = 0;
    if(obj == undefined || obj.length == 0) return -1;
    for(var i = 0;i < obj.length; i++){
        var curObj = obj[i];        
        if(curObj[propertyName] != undefined && curObj[propertyName] == propertyValue) {
            return level;}        
        if(curObj["children"] != undefined){
            var childSearchResult = getlvlByPropertyValue(curObj["children"], propertyName, propertyValue, ++level);
            if(childSearchResult > 0) {                
                return childSearchResult;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It'll return -1 if not found.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted scanObj to print out the current level you're at, you could pass the level down to scanObj

so:

```
var scanObj = function (obj, level, init) {
    if (level === undefined || init) {
      level = 0;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        console.log(obj[i].content);
        console.log(level);

        if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
            scanObj(obj[i].children, level);
        }
    }
};

scanObj(myObj, 0, true);
```

can probably be cleaned up so you don't need the init flag, but this should print the obj content as well as the level that the object is at.